# How to check if all Keys of the given Map are present in a one of the Maps contained within a List<Map<String, Object>> in Java efficiently?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

I have a list of maps `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Now I need to check whether a *map* exists in this *list* or not.

The *list* looks like:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
objectMap.put("id", "1");
objectMap.put("name", "name1");
objectMap.put("desc", "desc1");
objectMap.put("str", "str1");
contentList.add(objectMap);

Map<String,Object> objectMap2 = new HashMap<>();
objectMap2.put("id", "2");
objectMap2.put("name", "name2");
objectMap2.put("desc", "desc2");
objectMap2.put("str", "str2");
contentList.add(objectMap2);
```

now I have a map like:

```
Map<String,Object> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
expectedMap.put("id", "2");
expectedMap.put("name", "name2");
expectedMap.put("desc", "desc2");
```

I need to check whether `expectedMap` exists in the *list* or not.

I use this method to check it now. But I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do the same thing?

```
AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
contentList.forEach( m ->{
    if (m.entrySet().containsAll(expectedMap.entrySet())){
        found.set(true);
    }
});
return found.get();
```

And is there any way to make this method case-insensitive for `expectedMap` keys?

For example, I expect it also works for map:

```
Map<String,Object> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
expectedMap.put("Id", "2");
expectedMap.put("Name", "name2");
expectedMap.put("Desc", "desc2");
```

Comment: Based on what do you wanna compare the maps? on the id?

Comment: Hi, I want to compare all the <key,value> in the 'expectedMap', even if it doesn't contain an id. Maybe the list contains the duplicated results,  I only want to check it whether contains the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do the same
> thing?

In order to find out whether a single map in a list matches the given criteria you don't need to check every element, instead you need to find the first match and break the iteration.

To achieve that in place of `forEach` and `AtomicBoolean`, which act much slower than a simple `boolean` flag, you can use a plain `for` loop with a `break` statement inside it.

Or you can make use of the Java 8 streams with `anyMatch()` as terminal operation. `anyMatch()` - is a so-called short circuit operation, it'll break when the first element matching the given predicate will be found.

```
return contentList.stream()
    .anyMatch(map -> map.navigableKeySet().containsAll(expectedMap.navigableKeySet()));
```

> How to make this method case-insensitive for "expectedMap" keys?

It's not possible to achieve using hash-based collections.

But you can utilize in place of the `Map` the `NavigableMap` interface, and it's implementation `TreeMap` by providing a case-insensitive `Comparator`. And there's a predefined case-insensitive comparator strings provided by the `String` class as its static field.

```
List<NavigableMap<String, Object>> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
NavigableMap<String,Object> objectMap = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
...
```

Note, that maintaining an ordered collection has a cost. Contrary to `HashMap` which allows to add and retrieve entries in constant time **O(1)**, methods like `get()`, `put()`, `containsKey()` will perform in **O(log n)** with `TreeMap`.

*You can play around with* [*this Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rdl)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare keys in case-insensitive manner, a simple solution would be to generate a string of each map and then simply compare strings. Of course, this would be inefficient for large maps.

For example:

```java
// A simple method to concatenate entries of map as key=value pairs (in sorted key order)
private static String toKVString(Map<String,?> map, String delimiter) {
   return map.entrySet().stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
     .map(e -> String.format("%s=%s", e.getKey().toLowerCase(), e.getValue()))
     .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
}
```

Then, we can use simple string equality:

```java
final String delim = "/"; // choose something not found in keys or values
final String expectedMapAsString = toKVString(expectedMap, delim);
boolean found = contentList.stream()
    .anyMatch(map -> expectedMapAsString.equals(toKVString(map, delim)));
```